# React Hooks fade out effect on modal from onMouseLeave

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, use-state

This should be an easy one for most. The modal window after being opened from the button (thats triggered by onMouseEnter) needs an effect to fade out once the onMouseLeave is triggered. the modal "green square" should not move its position  at all but just fade out once the onMouseLeave or setOpenFalse it triggered. And they styles are in tailwind css. Thanks in advance ‍☠️

the sandbox is here - https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-transition-clicked-1egnp?file=/src/styles.css:0-191

```
import React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { useState, Fragment } from "react";
import { useBoolean } from "./hooks/useBoolean";
import "./styles.css";

export const Actions = ({ defaultSelected = "like" }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(defaultSelected);
  const [isOpen, setOpenTrue, setOpenFalse] = useBoolean();

  return (
    <div className="relative rounded">
      <button
        onMouseEnter={setOpenTrue}
        onMouseLeave={setOpenFalse}
        className={classNames("flex items-center gap-2 rounded px-2 py-1", {
          "": isOpen
        })}
      >
        {selected && <Fragment>open modal</Fragment>}
        {isOpen && (
          <div className="absolute mt-20 left-0 flex justify-center items start h-12">
            <div className="bg-green-700 w-24 h-36 shadow grid grid-flow-col  px-2 py-1 gap-2 animate-mount"></div>
          </div>
        )}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Actions;

.animate-mount {
  animation: mount 0.4s linear;
}

@keyframes mount {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit micromanage-y, but you could add two more states to track when the button element has been entered and exited.

1. Set the modal open and set entered on mouse enter, and on mouse leave set entered false, set exited true, and then set a timeout to subsequently set open and exited false.
2. Create an `.animate-unmount` animation that animates only the opacity.

The unmounting animation and `setTimeout` should be roughly the same duration.

styles.css

```
.animate-mount {
  animation: mount 0.4s linear;
}

@keyframes mount {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.animate-unmount {
  animation: unmount 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes unmount {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

Reactions.js

```
export const Actions = ({ defaultSelected = "like" }) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(defaultSelected);
  const [isOpen, setOpenTrue, setOpenFalse] = useBoolean();
  const [isEntered, setEnteredTrue, setEnteredFalse] = useBoolean();
  const [isExited, setExitedTrue, setExitedFalse] = useBoolean();

  return (
    <div className="relative rounded">
      <button
        onMouseEnter={() => {
          setOpenTrue();
          setEnteredTrue();
        }}
        onMouseLeave={() => {
          setEnteredFalse();
          setExitedTrue();
          setTimeout(() => {
            setOpenFalse();
            setExitedFalse();
          }, 500);
        }}
        className={classNames("flex items-center gap-2 rounded px-2 py-1", {
          "": isOpen
        })}
      >
        {selected && <Fragment>open modal</Fragment>}
        {isOpen && (
          <div className="absolute mt-20 left-0 flex justify-center items start h-12">
            <div
              className={classNames(
                "bg-green-700 w-24 h-36 shadow grid grid-flow-col  px-2 py-1 gap-2",
                {
                  "animate-mount": isEntered,
                  "animate-unmount": isExited
                }
              )}
            ></div>
          </div>
        )}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-hooks-fade-out-effect-on-modal-from-onmouseleave]